# Access VBA lookup folder and create if does not exist DLOOKUP

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a small program using Access 2010 and am using the below to check for a folder and if it doesn't exist, then create it, which works:

```
'need code to create folder
    If Dir("C:\Michael\Test", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ("C:\Michael\Test")
    Else
        'do nothing for directory already exists
    End If
```

However, I need to modify this.  The path can change depending on what the user has selected.  At the moment the path is built up and saved in a table ("tmpDestFolders") in field ("FlatFile").

In effect, I need to lookup whatever this value is, but the below does not work - how can I changed it so it will check what ever the field value is?  I just keep receiving error 76 invalid path:

```
'need code to create folder
    If Dir(DLookup("FlatFile", "tmpDestFolders"), vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (DLookup("FlatFile", "tmpDestFolders"))
    Else
        'do nothing for directory already exists
    End If
```

Comment: If "FlatFile" contains an invalid path, you will receive that error. So what do you look up?

Comment: "FlatFile" contains the whole path e.g. c:\test\stuff\things

Comment: And what happens if you replace the path in your original code with that path?

Comment: mmm same message - why is that?

Comment: _MkDir_ can only create a folder one level down.

Comment: ah, so it can! 10 points : -D  How do I get round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an API call:

```
Private Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal lpPath As String) As Long
```

and then simply:

```
MakeSureDirectoryPathExists DLookup("FlatFile", "tmpDestFolders")
```

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way, IMO :

```
Function FolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FolderExists = ((GetAttr(strPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)
End Function
```

```
Function CreateFolderIfNotExists(Directory As String)
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    Exists = FolderExists(Directory)
    If (Exists = False) Then
        MkDir Directory
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

@Gustav's Example is great as it's a one liner. My function while it contains more lines of code adds a flag option that if you choose to do so will create the directory for you if you set it to true. It's a nice one to add to the library. It's based off of the Access Master's (Allen Brown) function [Folder Exists](http://allenbrowne.com/func-11.html)

```
Function FolderExistsCreate(DirectoryPath As String, CreateIfNot As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim Exists As Boolean
    On Error GoTo DoesNotExist
    Exists = ((GetAttr(DirectoryPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)

    If Exists Then
        FolderExistsCreate = True
    Else
        ' Doesn't Exist Determine If user Wants to create
        If CreateIfNot Then
            MkDir DirectoryPath
            FolderExistsCreate = True
        Else
            FolderExistsCreate = False
        End If
    End If
    Exit Function
DoesNotExist:
    FolderExistsCreate = False
End Function
```

**Notes:** This can easily be called for example if you just want to create a directory if it does not exist like:

```
Call FolderExistsCreate(strPath, True)
```

Or if you want to test if a folder exists then create if not like:

```
' Check for User Specified 'Local' Dir Inbound Dir
If FolderExistsCreate(strPath, True) Then
    ValidateInboundLocal = True
Else
    ValidateInboundLocal = False
End If
```

Or if you just want to check for a directory without creating it like:

```
' Check for User Specified 'Local' Dir Inbound Dir
If FolderExistsCreate(strPath, False) Then
    ValidateInboundLocal = True
Else
    ValidateInboundLocal = False
End If
```