# How to save/export a pdf to a certain folder using VBA

Tags: vba, file, ms-access, save, report

I created a database in Access.

I created a report linked to a table in this DB that is run by a macro which creates a file (exports) through VBA onto my desktop.

I check the directory (i.e. desktop), create a year folder (i.e. 2020) if not created.
I check inside that folder, create a month folder (i.e January) if not created and then a day folder etc. for every month.

I am struggling to output the file to this location when it has completed these checks.
How do I word it while keeping the `DoCmd.OutputTo` etc?

```vb
Function Reportmacro()
On Error GoTo Reportmacro_Err
   
    ' Check for year folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:TEST\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:TEST\" & Year(Date)
    End If

     ' Check for month folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False)
    End If
    
    ' Check for day folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date)
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Changeover Car Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", "CCReport" & Day(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    End If
    
Reportmacro_Exit:
    Exit Function

Reportmacro_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Reportmacro_Exit

End Function
```

At the moment it is going to a "TEST" folder but same logic applies.

Comment: maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447395/access-vba-lookup-folder-and-create-if-does-not-exist-dlookup

Comment: You need to add the path with the filename, in `DoCmd.OutputTo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, code remains the same, only added the folder path to the file name:

```
Function Reportmacro()
On Error GoTo Reportmacro_Err

    Dim fPath as String
   
    ' Check for year folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:TEST\" & Year(Date), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:TEST\" & Year(Date)
    End If

     ' Check for month folder and create if needed
    If Len(Dir("H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir "H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False)
    End If
    
    ' Check for day folder and create if needed
    fPath = "H:TEST\" & Year(Date) & "\" & MonthName(Month(Date), False) & "\" & Day(Date)
    If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir fPath
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Changeover Car Report", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", fPath & "\" & "CCReport" & Day(Date) & "_" & Month(Date) & "_" & Year(Date) & ".pdf", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
    End If
    
    
Reportmacro_Exit:
    Exit Function

Reportmacro_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Reportmacro_Exit

End Function
```

check the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.outputto

Comment: Thank you so much it works like a charm, I even tested it by setting my computer date to 2021 + a random month -> created all the folders and placed it in with the date.

Comment: _it works like a charm_ ... Then please mark as answered.